# Return a JSON string if mySQL query returns true

Tags: php, mysql

I have a `PHP` code, that will run a Select query to check if a particular `personName` is present. If it is present we should return a `JSON` stating so, and if not present we should send a `JSON` response stating the same.

My code so far;

```
$rst= mysql_query("select* from Person
where personname='Labby'");


 while($r= mysql_fetch_array($rst) ){

// Now what ??
}
```

// How do i know if `$rst= mysql_query("select* from Person
where personname='Labby'");` , returned true or false ? and depending on that create a JSON response. How can i do this ?

Comment: `mysql_query` returns result resouce id not a boolean. Also this does not make sense `If it is present we should return a JSON stating so, and if not present we should send a JSON response stating the same.` So you need to define exactly what do you mean by `JSON` and `JSON response`

Comment: Don't use `mysql_` functions. They've been deprecated (http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php). Use `PDO` or `mysqli_`.

Comment: @JonathanM,`mysql_` functions are not **deprecated**! There is a hell ton of difference between *deprecated* and *discouraged*.

Comment: @Juicy, easy bro. It is deprecated, but softly. Here's the note: http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either switch your query to use `COUNT(*)` and retrieve the value, or use [`mysql_num_rows()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php) (or the mysqli or PDO equivalent).

Comment: You mean like  $rst.mysql_num_rows(); ? Can you show me a sample code

Comment: ... There are a number of examples on the page linked to.

Answer (score 1):

For SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE, EXPLAIN and other statements returning resultset, mysql_query() returns a resource on success, or FALSE on error.

from http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php:

```
// Perform Query
$result = mysql_query($query);

// Check result
// This shows the actual query sent to MySQL, and the error. Useful for debugging.
if (!$result) {
    $message  = 'Invalid query: ' . mysql_error() . "\n";
    $message .= 'Whole query: ' . $query;
    die($message);
}

// Use result
// Attempting to print $result won't allow access to information in the resource
// One of the mysql result functions must be used
// See also mysql_result(), mysql_fetch_array(), mysql_fetch_row(), etc.
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo $row['firstname'];
    echo $row['lastname'];
    echo $row['address'];
    echo $row['age'];
 }
```

Comment: Well, i did that, but at both success and fail it returns Success.

Comment: I would try our quodlibetor's code next, you may also want to review the various linked pages and there are alot of examples on them.

Answer (score 1):

The trick here is to realize that `$r` will be false if it can't find anything, which means that the loop will exit (or never start) if mysql can't find what you're looking for.

You can do something like:

```
$rst= mysql_query("select* from Person
where personname='Labby'");

$return = array();
while($r= mysql_fetch_array($rst) ){
    $return[] = $r;
}

if (count($return) > 0) {
    echo json_encode($return);
}
else {
    echo '{"success": false}'
}
```

obviously you'll want to adjust the "true" and "false" return values to something that makes sense for your app

Comment: I get this error `Call to undefined function array_length() `

Comment: right, that's because `array_length` does not exist. I meant to say `count`; fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Before handling the fetch, you should test if `$rst` is NULL first.

```
if($rst)
    while($r = mysql_fetch_array)
```

Mysql_query documentation :

> Return Values
>
> For SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE, EXPLAIN and other statements returning resultset, mysql_query() returns a resource on success, or FALSE on error.
>
> For other type of SQL statements, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, DROP, etc, mysql_query() returns TRUE on success or FALSE on error.
>
> The returned result resource should be passed to mysql_fetch_array(), and other functions for dealing with result tables, to access the returned data.
>
> Use mysql_num_rows() to find out how many rows were returned for a SELECT statement or mysql_affected_rows() to find out how many rows were affected by a DELETE, INSERT, REPLACE, or UPDATE statement.
>
> mysql_query() will also fail and return FALSE if the user does not have permission to access the table(s) referenced by the query.